# AWS LBS maximum request rate does not clear

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

In LBS I have message " "A request made to AWS Config exceeds the maximum request rate permitted for your account."

Unfortunately I do not know what is my current limit.
I found this page but it does not help me to get the point.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html

[image]

Comment: What is "LBS"? I've been using AWS a long time and nothing comes to mind. Do you mean "ELB"?

Answer (score 0):

This is, essentially, a cosmetic bug that can be triggered by the AWS console when looking at ALBs.  It doesn't impact your load balancer, and isn't actually even about the load balancer.  It's about how the console is gathering data for the display on the page.

When the console makes too many consecutive calls to the AWS Config service API, looking for the balancer's configuration history, this limit can be reached, and the underlying error is displayed.

See https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-application-loadbalancer/discussion/-L9pdappnw2XZVnFkFHL/A%20request%20made%20to%20AWS%20Config%20exceeds%20the%20maximum%20request%20rate%20permitted%20for%20your%20account.